# Sorting date and time with jQuery in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with date and time and other texts. I want to sort the table in descending order for the date and time. I tried various method some are looking at the date only but i want both date and time to be ordered.

Thanks!

This is the code i got from the internet and tried but it is not coming out the way i wanted.
Fiddle has everything: [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Hive/6wbybfc4/6/)

```
var john = $.makeArray($(".foobar"));
john.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date( $(a).text() ) < new Date( $(b).text() );
    });
$("#alice tr").html(john);
```

Comment: Update your fiddle to also load jQuery: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: There's a couple of issues here, but the major one is that your date strings cannot be parsed to a date very easily. You will need to do a lot of string manipulation to read them properly. Can you change that date format or the HTML at all?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Sorry for that! i have updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright a few things I noticed

- Forgot to load jQuery in jsfiddle
- You were sorting the cells instead of the rows, you want to sort the rows
- Helps to use the date as a numeric string (unless you want to use js to convert it as well)
- Always store data you're manipulating in data atttributes (as per HTML5), it makes it more efficient and easy to manipulate
- Descending order in this situation would be bDate - aDate, not aDate - bDate (if you want to offer both in the function, of course you can make a simple conditional to do so)

Here's the forked and updated jsdfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/GioLogist/ujtyzu09/

```js
var john = $.makeArray($(".foobar"));
john.sort(function(a, b) {

    var aDate = new Date($(a).data('date'));
    var bDate = new Date($(b).data('date'));
    return (bDate) - (aDate);
    
});
$("#alice").html(john);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  padding: 4px;
}

table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>pro</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>notes</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="alice">
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-05-23 03:10">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="statuschange">icon</span> 23 may, 03:10
            </td>
            <td>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae ut consequatur, facere quaerat Est.</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-09-22 03:10">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="comment">icon</span> 22 sep, 03:10
            </td>
            <td>Nemo consectetur saepe possimus, dolor vero excepturi voluptas! </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-05-28 11:19">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="request">icon</span> 28 may, 11:19
            </td>
            <td>Iure, nam cum perspiciatis, doloribus</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-07-16 17:05">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="notes">icon</span> 16 jul, 17:05
            </td>
            <td>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quam assumenda ab.</td>
            <td>updated date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-07-16 21:05">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="notes">icon</span> 16 jul, 21:05
            </td>
            <td>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quam assumenda ab.</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-12-12 21:05">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="notes">icon</span> 12 dec, 21:05
            </td>
            <td>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quam assumenda ab.</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="foobar" data-date="2016-6-10 21:05">
            <td>img</td>
            <td>
                <span class="notes">icon</span> 10 june, 21:05
            </td>
            <td>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quam assumenda ab.</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Added a few extra rows btw, just while I was testing.

Comment: 1) If you're going to steal someone elses code, at least have the decency to credit them. 2) Your `sort()` function is wrong, although it may work by coincidence

Comment: @Beekeeper no problem, glad to help!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Woah. Relax, man. Our code is entirely different, aside from the fact that mine works and yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your sorting logic, such as the fact you're sorting the `.foobar` elements, not their parent `tr`. However the most major problem is that the format of the date in your HTML cannot be parsed by a `Date()` object.

The easiest way to fix this would be to add a `data` attribute on each `.foobar` element which holds a parsable date string which you can use in the sorting logic, like this:

```js
$('tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aDate = new Date($(a).find('.foobar').data('date'));
    var bDate = new Date($(b).find('.foobar').data('date'));
    return aDate < bDate ? -1 : aDate > bDate ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>pro</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>notes</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="alice">
        <tr>
            <td>img</td>
            <td class="foobar" data-date="2016-05-23 03:10">
                <span class="statuschange">icon</span> 23 may, 03:10
            </td>
            <td>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae ut consequatur, facere quaerat Est.</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>img</td>
            <td class="foobar" data-date="2016-09-22 03:10">
                <span class="comment">icon</span> 22 sep, 03:10
            </td>
            <td>Nemo consectetur saepe possimus, dolor vero excepturi voluptas! </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>img</td>
            <td class="foobar" data-date="2016-05-28 11:19">
                <span class="request">icon</span> 28 may, 11:19
            </td>
            <td>Iure, nam cum perspiciatis, doloribus</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>img</td>
            <td class="foobar" data-date="2016-07-16 17:05">
                <span class="notes">icon</span> 16 jul, 17:05
            </td>
            <td>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quam assumenda ab.</td>
            <td>updated date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>img</td>
            <td class="foobar" data-date="2016-07-16 21:05">
                <span class="notes">icon</span> 16 jul, 21:05
            </td>
            <td>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quam assumenda ab.</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works on Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari for some reason.